# uninitialized constant RailsAdmin (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I cloned an app from bitbucket.

I ran `bundle install`

Now when I am trying to run the app with `rails s` I am getting below error.

> /home/project/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:1:in `': uninitialized constant RailsAdmin (NameError)

Here's what I have in my `routes`,

```
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
```

Please help

Comment: I saw this and hence I gave what I have in routes file. Doesn't help

Comment: What is in your /home/project/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, caused by using the wrong ruby version with rails_admin. In my case I should have been using ruby 1.9.3 for a project that was using rails_admin 0.4.9. Using a newer ruby version resulted in this error.